# How to move axis labels to the outer border when using center position

Tags: chart.js

In Chart.js I can create a scatter plot with centered axes by using the position attribute options -> scales -> x -> position as shown [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/scale-options/center.html). When doing this though, the axis labels move up into the center of the chart as well. How can I have centered axes and ticks but leave the axis labels themselves at the outer borders of the chart?

[image]

> const sampleConfig = {
> type: 'scatter',
> data: data,
> options: {
> responsive: true,
> plugins: {
> title: {
> display: true,
> text: 'Axis Center Positioning'
> }
> },
> scales: {
> x: {
> min: -100,
> max: 100,
> title: { display: true, text: 'X-Label'}
> },
> y: {
> min: -100,
> max: 100,
> title: { display: true, text: 'Y-Label'}
> }
> }
> },
> };

Comment: I don't think it's possible out of the box. The only way, without implementing a custom plugin, is to use "align" option of the title to move it but always inside the chart area.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to find a solution so I resorted to faking it by doing this:

- Create another set of x and y axes
- Hide their ticks marks and disable the grid display
- Move the titles from the original axes to the new ones
- Set their position to the left/bottom respectively

> ```
> x1: {
>           title: {
>             display: true,
>             text: 'X Title',
>             padding: 20
>           },
>           display: true,
>           position: 'bottom',
>           grid: {
>             drawOnChartArea: false, 
>           },
>           ticks: {
>             display: false,
>           },
>         },
>     }
> ```

Comment: Bug entered: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/11307

Comment: Your solution is excellent and you should not dismiss it; on the contrary, it seems to me it conforms to chart.js philosophy - that is, you need to be creative.  And I think that is not a bug, but a feature request, and an unlikely one to be tackled soon in my opinion. After all, there's a solution (yours) but you can also easily implement your [custom axes](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/axes.html#new-axes) if you want to implement absolute placement of its title.